# Does identifying the preimages of a finite covering results in a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, quotient-spaces

Let $p:Y \mapsto X$ be a **finite** covering map, and let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $Y$ induced by $p$: $y_1 \sim y_2$ iff $p(y_1)=p(y_2)$.

> By definition, $p$ descends to the quotient, i.e. we have an induced continuous map: $\tilde p:Y/\sim\, \, \, \mapsto \, X$. Clearly $\tilde p$ is bijective. Must it be a homeomorphism?

I am fine with assuming that $X$ is Hausdorff, but not that $Y$ is compact. (If $Y$ were compact, then $Y/\sim$ would also be compact, hence $\tilde p$ would be a continuous bijection from compact to Hausdroff, thus a homeomorphism).

I think that if $p$ is not finite, then $\tilde p$ does not need to be a homeomorphism: Take e.g. $Y=\mathbb{R},X=\mathbb{S}^1$, and $p(t)=e^{it}$. Then $Y/\sim \,\, \cong \,[0,2\pi)$ which is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: That's not a counterexample: we identify points that are a multiple of $2\pi$ apart. Or, $p$ is a group homeomorphism and we mod out as groups: the kernel is $2\pi \Bbb Z$. So we do get the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always true, even for nonfinite coverings. Your counterexample is not one, as $Y/\sim$ is then $[0,2\pi]$ with $0\sim 2\pi$, that is, a circle.

The proof is quite easy : $\tilde p$ is quite clearly continuous and bijective as you pointed out. We want to prove that its inverse, $h$ is also continuous.

Continuity is local  : let $x\in X$ and let $U$ be a small open set containing $x$ such that $p^{-1}(U)\cong U\times I$ (where $I$ is discrete) as spaces over $U$.

Then the restriction of $h$ to $U$ factors as $U\to Y\to Y/\sim$, where the first map is $u\mapsto (u,i)$ for some fixed $i\in I$. Both these maps are continuous, so $h_{\mid U}$ is continuous as well, so $h$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that you are correct. Do you think that this result holds whenever $p$ is a local homeomorphism? (it seems to me that we do not really use here the special covering property in any essential way...).

Comment: A surjective local homeomorphism should work indeed, the only that matters is that locally, you can continuously get up to $Y$ and get an antecedent (so even a map that has local sections everywhere is enough)

Answer (score 1):

This is true for any quotient map $p : Y \to X$. Covering maps (or more generally local homeomorphisms) are open maps, hence quotient maps.

See for example [A question regarding the property of a quotient map.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873107/a-question-regarding-the-property-of-a-quotient-map/2873128#2873128) .